# How to set background to edittext in android?

Tags: android

I am using custom drawable to set background of edit text.Following is the code for edit text background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<corners android:radius="1dp" />

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#595C65" />

<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
```

It displays the edit box with rectangle background .But i want to set edit text background with L shape(set left and bottom backgrounds).

Without using external images and i want to set these background via drawable xmls.

Expected output:
[image]

Current output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for these:

**text.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />           
        </shape>
    </item>

   
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />   
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="3px" android:left="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />           
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

**main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/text"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:password="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Without using external images we can get a output with the help of `drawable text.xml`

Comment: Try these and tell me what happened?

Comment: Yes i got it...U really removed my head ache.. :) :) :)

Answer (score -2):

Using a drawable this should work :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#555555" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Please read my question.Your answer is not correct for my need

Comment: No this is not the answer for my need

Comment: Hey this is not the answer.I think you understand my question in a wrong way.

Comment: You modified the Expected with the Current and that is why I did not understand it...