# How to make a "L" shaped edit text drawable selector in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

**I am trying to create a EditText as below**

[image]

**Question:**

- How can i write a selector for this and set as background
- I do not want to place a image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a  `<layer-list>` to accomplish what you want. Taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448967/how-to-set-background-to-edittext-in-android)

**res/drawable/text.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />   
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#000000" />   
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:bottom="3px" android:left="3px">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />           
        </shape>
    </item> 
</layer-list>
```

**res/layout/activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:background="@drawable/text"
    android:layout_width="170dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:password="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: He does not want to use drawable

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla *I do not want to place a image*. I presume he is talking about 9 patch :)

Comment: But 9 patch uses drawables, which actually creates an image. My answer just uses the color element. Its up to you after all

Answer (score 1):

This would work

1. Layout

   ```
   <EditText
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
       android:ems="10"
       android:layout_margin="5dp"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:hint="Email"
       android:background="@drawable/test_edit"
       android:id="@+id/editText" />
   ```
2. Layer_list

   ```
   <item android:drawable="@color/lightBlue"/>
   <item android:drawable="@color/darkBlue" android:left="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
   ```
3. Color

   ```
   darkBlue #ff1ca9ff

   lightBlue #ffb6f1ff
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this may help you but I would just create through the xml and use the Android 4.4 theme to style it L shaped. I would then set the background color to blue. This is how it done:

Create the `color.xml` file, to enter the color values you need.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <resources>
    <color name="dodgerblue">#1E90FF</color>
    <color name="lightskyblue_1">#B0E2FF</color>
 </resources>
```

Then, in your EditText, set the color as follows

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asdsadasdasd"
    android:textColor="@color/lightskyblue_1"
    android:background="@color/dodgerblue"
/>
```

If you need more colors, [here](http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm) is a useful link.
Hope this helps :)

Comment: I haven't used material, yet. Is the "L" shape the default in material theme for `EditText`? :)

Comment: Yes it is in android 4.4 theme