# Custom Android Layer-List

Tags: android, android-layout

I am tring below code for make shape look like below image, is that possible to make below screenshot by only layer-list concept?

***What i hv tried ?***

This is my code :

```
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#00f" />

        <padding android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:bottom="10dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />

        <padding
            android:left="2dp"
            android:right="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
        <solid android:color="#fff" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>

        <!-- set the shadow color here -->
        <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/generic_shadow_color" />
        <!-- setting the thickness of shadow (positive value will give shadow on that side) -->
        <padding
            android:bottom="2dp"
            android:left="-1dp"
            android:right="2dp"
            android:top="-1dp" />

        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
<!-- Background -->
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/generic_shadow_color" />

        <corners android:radius="7dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Result Shape i want is :

[image]

Comment: This looks like a normal `TextView` with a rounded rectangle below it. Have you considered using a `FrameLayout`? You could add a `View` to the bottom with a gray fill and black, rounded border. On top, you could add a normal `TextView`. See if that helps :)

Comment: m looking via layer-list only, any yes i hv tried via framelayout since this layout is used multiple times in my app so dont want it to make heavy via custom nested layout...is that possible with layer-list concept

Comment: Check this `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448967/how-to-set-background-to-edittext-in-android/22453022#22453022` but I am not sure about this.

Comment: @Naruto i hv already did that inside part in above code but things is it not going in center ...it overlaping