# Is it possible to hide an EditText line?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Can you hide the line in an EditText? For example, I am using an EditText for login and the background color is dark. I want to use an ImageView of a white line below an edit text and just have the edit text above the line. Please note I'd like the EditText to still have a hint, just not a line.

Comment: you can try this one

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22448967/how-to-set-background-to-edittext-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
android:background="@null"
```

On your EditText, you could also use a color